# How to adjust longtable to linewidth

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I am working with classicthesis and have a fairly complicated overall doc so I can't really post a MWE (sorry, fairly new to LaTeX). I am posting a few packages though that I believe may stand in relation to the table.
My problem: I am using a longtable which automatically spreads across multiple pages. Everything works fine except that it exceeds the width of the text (despite defining the columns using \linewidth).

Could you help me identify what I am doing wrong or how I can match table width with linewidth?

Thanks a ton!

```
\usepackage{calc, longtable, ltablex, booktabs,array, caption, enumitem}
\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}

\begin{spacing}{.7}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{x{0.35\textwidth} x{0.25\textwidth} x{0.4\textwidth}}
    \caption{Example table}\label{tab:example}  \\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Column One}} & {\textbf{Column Two}} & {\textbf{Column Three}}
    \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %%%%
    \caption{Example table (cont.)}  \\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Column One}} & {\textbf{Column Two}} & {\textbf{Column Three}}
    \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \endhead
    %%%%
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continue on the next page}
    \endfoot
    %%%%
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    %%%%

        Content & Content & Content   \tabularnewline
        Content & Content & Content   \tabularnewline

\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
```

Comment: it doesn't do any harm but `{\textbf{Column Two}}` could have less braces: `\textbf{Column Two}`  or  none: `\bfseries Column Two`

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
\begin{longtable}
      {x{0.35\textwidth} x{0.25\textwidth} x{0.4\textwidth}}
```

but each column has `\tabcolsep` (default 6pt) space either side so you will be 36pt too wide.

try

```
\begin{longtable}
      {@{}x{0.35\textwidth} x{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth - 24pt\relax} x{0.4\textwidth}@{}}
```

so you remove the padding from the sides with `@{}` and save 24pt in the middle column (or of course you could distribute it differently and remove some from each column)

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. However, the table is still wider than the remaining text in the document. Also tried your code replacing ```\textwidth```  with ```\linewidth``` but also no success. Any ideas why this problems may persist?

Comment: it should not be, but as you provided not test document it's hard to know what else may be affecting this.Oh I assumed `\tabcolsep` is 6pt you could print `\the\tabcolsep` to make sure or replace 24pt in my answer by `4\tabcolsep` @Christian

Answer (score 1):

I would use  the `xltabular` environment (the package loads `ltablex`, but saves the hassle of having to add `keepXColumns`) , with the specifications `>{\hsize)xx\hsize`  to have columns of different widths):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{array, setspace}
\usepackage{calc, longtable,xltabular, booktabs, array, caption, enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{spacing}{.7}
\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.05\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.20\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
    \caption{Example table}\label{tab:example} \\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Column One}} & {\textbf{Column Two}} & {\textbf{Column Three}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %%%%
    \caption{Example table (cont.)} \\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Column One}} & {\textbf{Column Two}} & {\textbf{Column Three}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    %%%%
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continue on the next page}
    \endfoot
    %%%%
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    %%%%
        Content & Content & Content \\
        Content & Content & Content
\end{xltabular}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard for your reply! While the overall table keeps to the textwidth, it doesn't seem to find the ```xltabular``` package (TexStudio shows a dotted line under the usepackage command). I assume this is why the distribution of columns and breaking of words and lines also does not work.

Comment: @Christian: What is your distribution?

Comment: I am working with MikTeX in TexStudio

Comment: `xltabular` is not in the basic installation. Install it with MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Will give this a try! As I will have to transfer the document to a colleague later on working on a Mac (I guess MacTeX), will this be compatible?

Comment: He should have a graphic interface to TeXLiveUtility, which does the same job as MPM for MiKTeX distributions, if the package is not already installed.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: In a MWE, your solution works fine. However, in my full document (classicthesis with multiple docs and previous editors), the text sometimes overruns columns and does not break correctly. Do you know of any other packages that xltabular conflicts with?